# Matlab Builder NE

Tags: wpf, performance, matlab, .net-assembly

I deployed a project into .NET assembly file.
One main function file (.m file) was dragged into the **Classes** section.
Three helper files were dragged into the **Shared Resources** section.

Under Settings, all Toolboxes path are checked. In my main function, I only used `norc` from Neural Toolbox. When I build the assembly file, it ended up at 12mb.

After referencing it in my main WPF project, the loading time is unbearable, and every time I perform some computation it takes about 10s to calculate.

When I run the function in Matlab, it takes less than 2 secs.

In sum, there are 2 problems that I am currently facing: 1.) large .NET assembly file and 2.) severe performance degradation.

I am using Win7 and Matlab 2012b. Has anyone faced such problems and solved them?

Comment: How big are your four files and the files used by them? And do you really need to add the helper files manually, perhaps they are there double now? I don't think that checking the toolboxes makes a difference as I always keep all checked and the dll never comes out so large. About performance: could you check whether the same amount of cpu usage occurs in both cases and are they both used on local drives?

Comment: My files are only 40kbytes. I recalled from the previous version of Matlab having all the toolbox checked, the .dll was only 47kb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you select the toolboxes can make a potentially large difference to the eventual size, especially if you have a large number of toolboxes. The dependency checker can't always determine exactly which functions your code calls (it might depend on many things at runtime), so it includes a fairly maximal set of things that the code could be calling. Unchecking unnecessary toolboxes that you know are not used can reduce the number of things it includes, sometimes quite significantly.

However, it may nevertheless need to include quite a lot of stuff, and it may just be large.

When your .NET code calls the .NET assembly deployed from MATLAB, it needs to start up the MCR, which can take quite a long time (nearly as long as MATLAB itself), and then do whatever it needs to. If you can keep the variable referring to the component alive somehow between calls, then you will only get that startup cost once.

Comment: Keeping the variable referring to the component alive? I referenced to the Matlab object once. I have MWArray object only within a function call, and that function call get every second. Were you referring to this issue?

Comment: Thanks! I sorted the issue as per your suggestion.